# Global variable in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to determine why my global variable isn't available in my browser console. Here is my top-level meteor javascript file contents:

```
     if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Meteor.startup(function () {

         Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");
         Carbrands = new Meteor.Collection("carbrands");
         Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");

         Posts.insert({post1:'post'});
         Carbrands.insert({post1:'post'});
         Comments.insert({post1:'post'});
      });
     }
```

(I can confirm that Posts, Carbrands, Comments are defined), but in the broswer, I get this (Posts is undefined):

[image]
however, when I add this line of code at the top:

```
Posts = null;

     if (Meteor.isServer) {
         Meteor.startup(function () {

      Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");
      Carbrands = new Meteor.Collection("carbrands");
      Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");

      Posts.insert({post1:'post'});
      Carbrands.insert({post1:'post'});
      Comments.insert({post1:'post'});
      });
     }
```

I get the following console output (Posts is null):

[image]

what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring Collections inside the `/lib` folder

So they will be available both `client/server`

Like [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) says `/lib` folder its a good place to declare collections

> lib/                      # common code like collections and utilities

Answer (score 3):

The code inside of the `Meteor.isServer` is only running on the server (not on the client). You need to define you collections outside of that check so they will be exposed to both.

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // do server things. Posts will be defined here.
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // do client things. Posts will be defined here.
}
```

As you codebase expands beyond a single file, you'll end up dividing it into directories like [this](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-where-should-i-put-my-files). In which case, your collection defintion will end up somewhere like `lib/collections/posts.js`, and will automatically be exposed to both the server and the client.